# PIC18F4550 Asynchronous USART Baud Rate

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, uart, baudrate

I am trying to implement a USART routine to transmit a string using PIC18F4550. I intend to transmit the message at 115200 baud rate in asynchronous mode. My PIC18F4550 is running at 48MHz using 20MHz external crystal and HSPLL_HS mode.

According to the PIC18F4550 datasheet below I have set the both TRISC6 and TRISC7 as 1.

[image]

I set TXSTA register as **0x20** to select Asynchronous mode and High baud rate speed.

[image]

I set RCSTA register as **0x90** to enable serial port.

[image]

To compute the correct SPBRG value corresponding to the desired baud rate of 115200, I used the formula given in the datasheet:

[image]

Based on this calculation, I get the SPBRG value of 25. And the following is the code for the full implementation:

```
// PIC18F4550 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1L
#pragma config PLLDIV = 5       // PLL Prescaler Selection bits (No prescale (4 MHz oscillator input drives PLL directly))
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2// System Clock Postscaler Selection bits ([Primary Oscillator Src: /1][96 MHz PLL Src: /2])
#pragma config USBDIV = 1       // USB Clock Selection bit (used in Full-Speed USB mode only; UCFG:FSEN = 1) (USB clock source comes directly from the primary oscillator block with no postscale)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config FOSC = HSPLL_HS  // Oscillator Selection bits (HS Oscillator, PLL enabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOR = ON         // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset enabled in hardware only (SBOREN is disabled))
#pragma config BORV = 3         // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting 2.05V)
#pragma config VREGEN = OFF     // USB Voltage Regulator Enable bit (USB voltage regulator disabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = OFF         // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = ON      // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config PBADEN = ON      // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as analog input channels on Reset)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    // Low-Power Timer 1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RE3 input pin disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = OFF         // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP enabled)
#pragma config ICPRT = OFF      // Dedicated In-Circuit Debug/Programming Port (ICPORT) Enable bit (ICPORT disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) are not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
#include <pic18f4550.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000

void USART_send_string(char *msg);

void main(void) {
    TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 1; 
    TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 1; 
    
    BAUDCONbits.BRG16 = 0;
    TXSTA = 0x20;
    RCSTA = 0x90;
    SPBRG = 25;

    USART_send_string("AT");
    
    while(1)
     {
     }
     }

void USART_send_string(char *msg)
{
    while (*msg != '\0')
    {
        while(TXIF == 0);
        TXREG = *msg;
        *msg++;
    }
}
```

As I do not have any serial to USB adapter, I used my logic analyzer to monitor the TX pin of PIC18F4550.

If I set the baud rate of the logic analyzer program to 115200, the data is not properly shown which mean the output from the PIC MCU is not at this baud rate.

[image]

However, when I use the auto baud rate feature, I was able to observe the message "AT" that was transmitted by MCU. But in this case, the logic analyzer detect it to have the baud rate of 28818.

[image]

What is causing this baud rate discrepancy? How can I make sure the output from Tx is truly at 115200 baud rate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the error:

```
TXSTA = 0x20;
```

You didn't set the BRGH bit but are working with this formula:
Baudrate = Fosc/[16*(n+1)]

Switch to:

```
TXSTA = 0x24;
```

Answer (score 0):

RX pin C7 should be set as input.

```
TRISC.TRISC7 = 1;                      //rx set to input
TRISC.TRISC6 = 0;                      //tx set to output
```